# OpenMP SIMD Vs multi-threaded

Tags: multithreading, openmp

Considering the fact that openmp uses simd model i.e. each instruction is executed by all the threads, so one should be careful while writing openmp parallel application, why should we prefer openmp over multi-threaded version of same algorithm ?

Comment: Because OpenMP is by far easier to write. Let me ask: Why should one be careful while writing OpenMP parallel application?

Comment: Because of false sharing, avoiding conditional statements ( because of SIMD)

Comment: Im not a openMP expert but as far I understand it  you easily create a multi-threaded application just by adding pragmas and convert it to a single core application just by changing  a compile flag. OpenMp creates the exact number of threads as you have cpus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP isn't SiMD only anymore from 3.0 onwards.

And common reasons are:

- Ease of use/Amount of code.
- One can compile the same code without -fopenmp flag and get "legacy code retro-compatibility". Obviously this has to do with the use of #pragma statements.